# Getting value from MAX(Date) Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the last supplier of an item, by using the MAX function. What I am trying to achieve is showing what the supplier name was for the row with the MAX(Date) for all the stock items (shown below as account links).

The code I am using bring up multiple dates for the same accountlink, and I am struggling to see why. My code is:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(TxDate) AS Date,
  ST.AccountLink,
  V.Account AS Supplier 

FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS ST 
  JOIN Vendor V on ST.DrCrAccount = V.DCLink

WHERE Module = 'AP' 
AND Id = 'OGrv'
GROUP BY ST.AccountLink, V.Account
ORDER BY AccountLink
```

But my results look like the below

[image]

Comment: Because you are grouping by `GROUP BY ST.AccountLink, V.Account`? Not `ST.AccountLink.` You need to show some sample starting data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
select AccountLink,Supplier,date from(SELECT 
ST.AccountLink,
V.Account AS Supplier,
TxDate as [date],
row_number()over(partition by ST.AccountLink order by TxDate desc)rownum

FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS ST 
  JOIN Vendor V on ST.DrCrAccount = V.DCLink

WHERE Module = 'AP' 
AND Id = 'OGrv')t
where t.rownum = 1
```

The group by has been removed and ranking function is used to achieve the output

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple subquery to select the last supplier.

```
    select X.supplier as LastSupplier, X.Date as lastDate,  X.AccountLink
    from _bvSTTransactionsFull X 
    where X.Date = (select max(date) 
                    from _bvSTTransactionsFull Y 
                    where Y.AccountLink=X.AccountLink)
```

The subquery extracts the last date for any accountLink, so you can use it on the outer where condition.